# How to wait for Storyboard in another class to complete

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

So I have two classes

**A. MainWindow

B. MoveObjects**

**1. MainWindow** - Calls MoveObject class method to perform the storyboard animation on canvas.

**2. MoveObjects** - Performs storyboard animations on canvas.

Everything is working fine. What I need is, once the animation is displayed on the Canvas, I want to call a method in MainWindow which is private. But, since its private, I can't call it from MoveObjects and I am unable to get the control back to MainWindow after the storyboard execution is completed.

Right now, its calls the MoveObjects class, displays the animation but doesn't come back to the calling class i.e. MainWindow.

How can I achieve this?

I tried the following code -

```
bg.DoWork += (s, el) =>
            {

                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                MoveObjects.AnimateMSU(expectedSKUQuantitiesAtPPS[(int)SKUTypes.Shirts],
                expectedSKUQuantitiesAtPPS[(int)SKUTypes.Pants],
                expectedSKUQuantitiesAtPPS[(int)SKUTypes.Shoes],
                expectedSKUQuantitiesAtPPS[(int)SKUTypes.Hats],
                StorageGridAnimationCanvas, "Finish");
            }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        };

        bg.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, el) =>
        {
             //Call a private method of current class
        };


        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

But, `bg.RunWorkerCompleted` is executed before the animation is displayed on the Canvas. How can I make class MainWindow wait for the MoveObjects class to get completely executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate here. Please find a code sample [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426120/Calling-a-method-in-Csharp-asynchronously-using-de).

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. It does the same thing. Executes the AnimateMSU method, comes back, then displays the actual animation on my window.